# what are the relations between the constant (a,b and c) so that the following system of linear equations has a unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

what are the relations between the constant (a,b and c) so that the following system of linear equations has a unique solution ?
$$
\begin{cases}
-x+y+2z=a\\
3x-y+z=b\\
-x+3y+4z=c\\
\end{cases}
$$

---

I used Gaussian elimination to reach this :
$$\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&0&(-7a+2b+3c)/10\\0&1&0&(-13a-2b+7c)/10\\0&0&1&(4a+b-c)/5\end{matrix}\right)$$
and the determinant of $$\left(\begin{matrix}-1&1&2\\3&-1&1\\-1&3&4\end{matrix}\right)$$ != 0
but i don't know how to infer the relations between (a,b,c) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the determinant is non-zero, it has an inverse and hence it always have a unique solution.

No constraint has to be imposed on $a,b,c$.